# Linux: make service run forever until I stop it? Node.js + Socket.io

Tags: linux, node.js, socket.io

I am new to linux so I am wondering how can I make service run forever? and automatically restart if it crashes or stops?

I am running Node.js + Socket.io as a chat server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 main options for node.js :

**Option 1 : [node-forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever)**

```
npm install forever -g
```

then you run your script by typing : `forever start myscript.js`

**Option 2 : [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)**

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

then you run your script by typing : `pm2 start myscript.js`

The main difference is that pm2 has zero downtime, a web interface, console monitor and a built-in load balancer. The web interface itself has proved an invaluable bonus for many of my projects.

I would recommend **forever in development mode**, and **pm2 in production**, the reason being that pm2 sometimes keeps the port in use when you kill it, so it's a bit annoying in dev when you restart all the time. Otherwise pm2 has a lot more features and has never disappointed me, I use it all the time.

Comment: I will try those also by any chance you would know how can I create subdomain to my chat? its like this: website.com:3000
Any way to make it chat.website.com ? 

Asking because seems like you know quite a bit about ports

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/)
It's a standard open source app for monitoring processes and restarting them if they fail.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Forever NPM](https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever) this is easy to use, i was also new but tried this my work gone easy :)

Answer (score 0):

For start you server you can use: `monit`, `forever`, `upstart` or `systemd`.

For [Forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever):

> Start a process:

```
forever start example.js
```

> Stop the process

```
forever stop example.js
```